# What is furrr's "black magic?"

Tags: r, environment-variables, furrr

I use the R package `furrr` for most of my parallelization needs, and basically never have issues with exporting things from my global environment to the cluster. Today I did and I have no idea why. The package documentation seems to describe the process by which global variables are sent to the clusters as "black magic." What is the black magic?

The `furrr::future_options` documentation says:

> Global variables and packages
>   By default, the future package will perform black magic to look up the global variables and packages that your furrr call requires, and it will export these to each worker. However, it is not always perfect, and can be refined with the globals and packages arguments.

As a secondary question: is there an elegant way to tell it to do its black magic, but *also* to export something it missed? Or, are the choices a) all black magic, or b) hard code everything in the `.options` argument?

Comment: w.r.t. the secondary question, you can add only missed objects in the "plan" with `, globals = structure(TRUE, add = "a")`  https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/future/vignettes/future-4-issues.html

Comment: and it is known that `future` doesn't always play nice with `data.table`

Comment: I love this question and it is tragic there is no answer yet. I have seen the same thing. Sometimes my globals show up and sometimes they don't... I am very interested in an answer to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't totally answer the question, but I think it points you in the right direction. From the "Globals" section of [this intro vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/future/vignettes/future-1-overview.html):

> It does this with help of the [globals](https://cran.r-project.org/package=globals) package, which uses static-code inspection to identify global variables. If a global variable is identified, it is captured and made available to the evaluating process.

There's also [this "Common Issues with Solutions" vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/future/vignettes/future-4-issues.html) (which @michael helpfully linked above) that discusses some common "gotcha" things that result from the static code eval in the globals package.

I found my way here because my `future_map()` code was failing to find the variables I referenced inside a `glue()` call. That vignette explained exactly why this happens.

As to why your code was sometimes working and sometimes not, hard to say. But as you can see, there is sufficient complexity going on under the hood that I'm not surprised if some seemingly unrelated change broke something. (For me this change was cleaning up my code and using `glue` instead of `paste` :shrug:)