# Environment/scoping in furrr: nesting get() in future_map()

Tags: r, scoping, furrr

I'm interested in learning more about how `furrr` finds stuff from the global environment, and asked generally about the [black magic](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60776810/8400969) it performs. Here's a specific example of a behavior I didn't understand and could use some help with: What do I need to change in either in the `future_map` call or in the `get` call  to return `"C"` and `"F"`?

```
# load furrr, describe "plan"
library(furrr)
nc<-2
plan(strategy = multiprocess, workers = nc)

# create objects

a<-list("A", "B", "C")
b<-list("D", "E", "F")


#works fine
future_map(1:5, function(foo){
    map(c("a", "b"), function(my_object_name){
        bar<-my_object_name
        print(bar)

    })
})


# object 'a' not found

future_map(1:5, function(foo){
        map(c("a", "b"), function(my_object_name){
            bar<-get(my_object_name)[[3]]
            print(bar)
    })
})
```

**EDIT**

It seems like this issue is not reproducible on all systems and may have to do with my installation of `furrr.` Despite the warning the package gives about multicore plans, this is an issue with `multiprocess` and `multisession` but not `plan(strategy=multicore,...`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I tripped across some known weird behavior with the `future` package with documented workarounds. See [vignette in future documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/future/vignettes/future-4-issues.html).

To add variables to the exported globals, use the `globals` argument in `future`, which translates in `furrr` to  `, .options = future_options(globals(structure=T, add="missing_object"`

I suspect this might have also been one of my problems:

> ...The above error occurs because, contrary to the master R process,
>   the R worker that evaluated the `future` expression does not have
>   `data.table` loaded. Instead the evaluation falls back to the
>   [.data.frame method, which is not what we want.
>
> Until the future framework manages to identify `data.table` as a
>   required package (which is the goal), we can guide future by
>   specifying additional packages needed...

Answer (score 0):

It is the `envir` that is creating the problem.  Specify the `envir` as the global environment to look for that object and `print`

```
library(furrr)
future_map(1:5, function(foo){
    map(c("a", "b"), function(my_object_name){
        bar <- get(my_object_name, envir = .GlobalEnv)[[3]]
        print(bar)
    })
 })
#[1] "C"
#[1] "F"
#[1] "C"
#[1] "F"
#[1] "C"
#[1] "F"
#[1] "C"
#[1] "F"
#[1] "C"
#[1] "F"
#[[1]]
#[[1]][[1]]
#[1] "C"

#[[1]][[2]]
#[1] "F"
#...
```

Comment: I had tried that without success. `> future_map(1:5, function(foo){
+         map(c("a", "b"), function(my_object_name){
+             bar<-get(my_object_name, envir=.GlobalEnv)[[3]]
+             print(bar)
+     })
+ })`
`Error in get(my_object_name, envir = .GlobalEnv) : object 'a' not found`

Comment: @Michael I assumed that you have created `a<-list("A", "B", "C");
b<-list("D", "E", "F")` in your global env (as showed in your post)

Comment: @Michael Please check your `ls()` for objects 'a', 'b', in case you are doing this on a fresh R session without that objects created

Comment: I believe I have: `ls()
[1] "a"     "b"   "nc"`

Comment: @Michael I also have that object `ls()#
 [1] "a"         "b" , ...`

Comment: @Michael Can you try. this outside `get("a", envir = .GlobalEnv)` may be there is some issue in your environment

Comment: @Michael also you can check the `ls` from inside the `map` `future_map(1:5, function(foo){
        map(c("a", "b"), function(my_object_name) ls(envir = .GlobalEnv))})`

Comment: Most interesting. `get("a")` returns the expected list. `ls()` inside the `map` call did not: `[1] "future.call.arguments" "has_future"            "is_bad_rlang_tilde" "version"`. Know what this means?

Comment: @Michael For me, it is giving that 'a'.  It could mean that your version of `furrr` would be one issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210071/discussion-between-michael-and-akrun).